# Double click required for performing ActionEvent in JButton

Tags: java, swing, jframe, actionlistener

I have created a simple Login Frame using a JFrame.
I have hardcoded validations wherein if a user enters **username** as *AKASH* and **password** as *12345* then ***Login Success*** is displayed below the Button else ***Wrong Password*** is displayed.

Everything is working fine.The only thing is :

> I have to double click to see the result after entering the details

Could anyone please help me on this.

Here is my code :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class LginForm extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    Container c;
    JTextField jt;
    JButton jb;
    JPasswordField jp;
    JLabel jl1,jl2;
    JLabel jl3 = new JLabel("Wrong Password");
    JLabel jl4 = new JLabel("Login Successful");


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LginForm lf = new LginForm();
        lf.setBounds(100, 50, 500, 400);
        lf.setVisible(true);
        lf.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    }

    public LginForm() {

        c = this.getContentPane();
        c.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        c.setLayout(null);

        jl1 = new JLabel("Enter Username");
        jl1.setBounds(50, 10, 100, 30);
        jl1.setFont(new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.ITALIC, 12));


        jl2 = new JLabel("Enter Password");
        jl2.setBounds(50, 100, 100, 30);
        jl2.setFont(new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.ITALIC, 12));


        jt = new JTextField();
        jt.setBounds(200,10,100,30);


        jp = new JPasswordField();
        jp.setBounds(200,100,100,30);


        jb = new JButton("login");
        jb.setBounds(130,180,80,30);
        c.add(jl1);
        c.add(jl2);
        c.add(jt);
        c.add(jp);
        c.add(jb);
        jb.addActionListener(this);



    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {


        if(event.getSource() == jb) {
            String usrname = jt.getText();
            String passwrd = String.valueOf(jp.getPassword());
            if(usrname.equals("Akash") && passwrd.equals("12345")) {
                jl4.setBounds(100, 230, 150, 40);
                jl4.setFont(new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.ITALIC, 12));
                c.add(jl4);
                c.remove(jl3);
            }
            else {
                jl3.setBounds(100, 230, 150, 40);
                jl3.setFont(new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.ITALIC, 12));
                c.add(jl3);
                c.remove(jl4);
            }
        }

    }


}
```

[This the login frame created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3br1t.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
c.add(jl4);
c.remove(jl3);
```

I would guess that after adding/removing components from the panel you need to invoked `repaint()` the panel.

This is only a guess because you should NOT be using a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. Let the layout manager determine the size/location of components based on the rules the layout manager.

Then when you add/remove components from a panel the basic logic would be:

```
panel.remove(...);
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

Read the Swing tutorial on [Using Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information.

### Note:

I would also suggest a simpler solution is to add the "message label" to the panel with text set to " ". Then you can simply use the `setText(...)` method of the label to change the message. This way you don't even need to worry about adding/removing components.

Comment: yeah that worked.
But could you elaborate the concept of repaint() required here.

Comment: Whenever you change a property of a component the component needs to be repainted. Normally when you change  Swing components the component will automatically revalidate() itself and repaint() itself so you don't need to do anything special. However. a panel is different. When adding/removing components from a panel the panel doesn't know when you are finished and you don't want to keep invoking the layout manager, so you need to do the revalidate() and repaint() manually once you have finished all the changes to the panel.

Comment: Apoligies as I am new to StackOverflow and do not have considerable amnt of reputation for upvote.

Comment: I did the upvote for you @camickr for the good explanation. :)